# Combining tables in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have two tables like this:

```
table 1:
a    b    data
---  ---  ----
a1   b1   1
a1   b2   2
a2   b1   3
a2   b2   4

table 2:
a    b    data
---  ---  ----
a1   b1   5
a1   b2   6
a2   b1   7
a2   b2   8
```

I need to combine them in the following way:

```
a    b    c    data
---  ---  ---  ----
a1   b1   1    1
a1   b2   1    2
a2   b1   1    3
a2   b2   1    4
a1   b1   2    5
a1   b2   2    6
a2   b1   2    7
a2   b2   2    8
```

The input tables are in two different files, and I need the output table to be written into a new file.

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1998770/2640636), but it's not asking exactly the same, and I need a new table in a new file, rather than a view.

It's not important that column `c` come after `a` and `b`.

I know that a column can be added with

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD c TEXT;
```

but that fills the new column with `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make a new table with the contents of two others?

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
  SELECT a, b, 1 AS c, data FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a, b, 2, data FROM table2;
```

is one easy way. Use [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) as needed to get the various database files all loaded into a single session and use the `schemaname.tablename` form of specifying table names.

---

You can also split it up into parts, if you want to add constraints or whatever to the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE table3(a TEXT, b TEXT, c INTEGER, data INTEGER);
INSERT INTO table3 SELECT a, b, 1, data FROM table1;
INSERT INTO table3 SELECT a, b, 2, data FROM table2;
```